# Good Lucene .NET alternative for ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net

Are there any good alternatives for [Lucene .NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net) to use in a ASP.NET website?

I want to index XML-, TXT-, PDF- and DOC-files.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any reasons not to use Lucene or were you just looking for alternatives?

Comment: Lucene.NET is not usable in a Medium Trust Level ASP.NET site. That's why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is late, but i think that Lucene.Net is now compatible with Medium Trust

see about midway in this post :

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2009/06/24/new-adventures-under-medium-trust/

**Update**

Adding this note for anyone else who finds this :
The final resolution of the issue is noted below. Short version : Lucene.Net officially runs under Medium Trust.

http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-169

Comment: Nice - even if they dont accept the patch it sounds like patching the source youself would be enough to get Lucene.Net working!

Comment: Yeah, found this post myself too and tried it, it works great! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't say if this is better than Lucene.NET but you might want to look at https://searcharoo.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Ironically, the only answer to the question (*alternative* to Lucene) got no ^'s.

Comment: http://www.searcharoo.net/ is a dead link with some "Buy this domain" and unrelated "related searches" links now.

Answer (score 4):

why not try solr?

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: Isn't solr lucene with some lipstick?

Comment: This is a Java alternative, I want a .NET alternative. I want to use it in a ASP.NET website. And it has to be able to run in a Medium Trust environment.

Comment: yes, lucene with lipstick :) but all that was asked is if there was an alternative to using lucene.net for an asp.net site (does not necessarily mean coded in .NET)... solr runs as a web service enabling it to be accessed from any language.

anyways, if the requirement is to be native .NET or NOT be java, yes, not a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

Searcharoo has been mentioned. https://searcharoo.codeplex.com/
It's fully C#/.NET (edit - original domain no longer accessible. The codeplex link is to the searcharoo source code and the project has not had any update since 2012).

Also from [this link](http://zooie.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/a-comparison-of-open-source-search-engines-and-indexing-twitter/):

- [Whoosh](http://whoosh.ca/) (purely Python, no C#/.NET bindings)
- [zettair](http://www.seg.rmit.edu.au/zettair/) (C; no C#/.NET bindings)
- [indri](http://www.lemurproject.org/indri/) (bindings for Java, PHP, C++, but not C#/.NET)
- [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) (for MySQL or PostgreSQL, or XML pipes)
- [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) (C++; has C#/.NET bindings)

Comment: Searcharoo project is currently dead

Comment: Searcharoo alraedy mentioned, the others aren't .Net. The post explicitly states it's for an ASP.NET web site.